# How to create a clickable map with location pin from address

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I would like to create a clickable preview with a pin on a given address in a map. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLsQM.png)

This preview would be created dynamically from either an address(preferred) or coordinates.

I want to be able to click the preview and be taken to the phones default map with the location loaded. I already know how to open the map and load a location, I just don't know how to make the map clickable or the best approach to creating the map.

I have tried MapView from React Native Maps wrapped in a touchableOpacity, however, taping the map doesn't work.

Comment: in MapView, there is onPress...you will get latlong from that...and set that latlong in Marker view that is inside the MapView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react native maps have onPress props, from which you can retrieve onPressed location,

```
onPress={async (event) => {
            this.handleMapPressed(event.nativeEvent.coordinate);
          }}
```